WFS: Smaller bounding box returns more matches than a larger one
I use the following WFS
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
When using an earth sized bounding box i get 19 features:
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?bbox=-90.000000%2C-180.000000%2C90.000000%2C180.000000%2Curn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A4326&request=GetFeature&resultType=hits&service=WFS&typeNames=ave%3AVerwaltungsEinheit&version=2.0.0
While instead using a smaller bounding box, the bbox noted in the capabilities for that feature, i get 455.
https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?bbox=50.237351%2C5.612726%2C52.528630%2C9.589634%2Curn%3Aogc%3Adef%3Acrs%3AEPSG%3A%3A4326&request=GetFeature&resultType=hits&service=WFS&typeNames=ave%3AVerwaltungsEinheit&version=2.0.0
Can someone explain this to me?

Probably the large request is too large and hence canceled.

Wouldn't that result into an error? And not an incorrect result.

maybe the axis order is wrong?

The axis order is correct.

Contact the service provider and ask. However, the bbox of data is <ows:LowerCorner>5.61272621358227 50.2373512078443</ows:LowerCorner> <ows:UpperCorner>9.5896343371016 52.5286304537958</ows:UpperCorner> and the default srsName is "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832". It may be that converting the whole World in EPSG:4326 into EPSG:25832 fails because the valid area of 25832 is much smaller.
